# Django rest framework post request not retrieving anything

Tags: python, django, postman

I am trying to create a user creation api and post create api, the 'Get' request works fine but the post request is always empty. If there is anything I missed or need to add to the views, because the get request works fine for the post app. What could be the possible errors that are occuring.

Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email',
                  'date_of_birth', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def save(self):
        print("saved")
        user = User(email=self.validated_data['email'],
                    username=self.validated_data['username'],
                    date_of_birth=self.validated_data['date_of_birth']
                    )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Below is the views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import User
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser


@api_view(['POST', ])
def registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)

        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("Hello")
            user = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'Successfuly registered a new User'
            data['date_of_birth'] = user.date_of_birth
            data['username'] = user.username
            data['email'] = user.email
            token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
            data['token'] = token
            return Response(data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

No matter the post request I always get an error saying this field is required,

[Here is the error -- screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnZL1.png)

Can anybody help me please, 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot you are sending data as query params with POST request. In Postman you should use `body` section with, for example, form-data option.

[image]

Comment: @user10944910 I updated the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Now its giving me an error on what could that be ?? TypeError: Object of type Token is not JSON serializable

Comment: `data['token'] = token` - you can't simply put an object to the response. You need to serialize it first into known format (JSON in your case)

Comment: Ohh I get it like ```token.key()``` should probably fix it then right